# how to add user control multiple times in runtime on a webpage in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html, webusercontrol

i'm having one user control in asp.net ,i just want to add the user control multiple times in a single web page in runtime in a separate table. How to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Page.LoadControl method to dynamically create a user control instance, and add it to a parent control like:

```
var uc = Page.LoadControl("~/uc.ascx");
this.Panel1.Controls.Add(uc);
```

Everytime the page posts back, you have to recreate the UC, fyi.

Comment: thanks for reply. I'm having some more queries these are as-- If i want to add multiple user control then is there requirement of multiple panel control? & when i add the user control like this then how can i access particular user control at run time for further development?

Comment: @Priyanka a single panel can have many controls, so there can be as many UC's in one panel.  That is fine.  You can use one of multiple options to access the control.  You can store a reference of the user control in a List and access it from the list.  Or you can use Panel1.FindControl("ID") to access it later, or at the time you call Page.LoadControl, if you know what you want to do to the control then, you can do it right at that point.  Just cast the user control to the correct user control class type.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim tbl As New Table
Dim tr1 As New TableRow
tbl.Rows.Add(tr1)
Dim td1 As New TableCell
tr1.Cells.Add(td1)
Dim ctl As New CustomControl
ctl.Text = "Toto"
td1.Controls.Add(ctl)
```

It is some old code, which was working in .net 1.1 but it should still work.

Answer (score 1):

So that you can reference each created control, you have to assign a unique id to each control:

> ```
>   Dim tempUserControl As UserControl
> ```

```
    tempUserControl = Page.LoadControl("~/UserControl1.ascx")
    tempUserControl.ID = "uniquename1"
    testPanel.Controls.Add(tempUserControl)
    tempUserControl = Page.LoadControl("~/UserControl1.ascx")
    tempUserControl.ID = "uniquename2"
    testPanel.Controls.Add(tempUserControl)
```

Then you can access the control on a later postback:

```
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim tempUserControl As WebUserControl1
    tempUserControl = testPanel.FindControl("uniquename1")
End Sub
```